# xfce panel and whisker menu hidden after removing monitors

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm running xubuntu 18.04. I recently switched from a triple-monitor setup to single monitor -- and now the xfce panel and the whisker menu don't show up on the desktop. I can see`xfce4-panel` in the process list, I just think that it's displaying on a screen that doesn't exist. Not sure how to fix this, since I can't click on the panel to unlock and re-position it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Terrance's lead, I opened `xfce4-settings-manager`, but then opened `Panel` instead of `Display`.

I had previously set `Output` to `Monitor 2`, which did not exist. I set this to `Primary`, which  fixed the problem.

[image]

Comment: You can have the answer.  I didn't even think about checking the Panel itself to make sure it was set to the primary monitor.  Good find!  =)  +1